# import a sencha architect project into eclipse with phonegap

Tags: eclipse, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a small sencha 2 project complete and want to import it into eclipse with phonegap. I want to keep the MVC file structure, how do I set up my android project in eclipse to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the starting guide in the Phonegap docs on this link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

After following the Android guide, put your Sencha stuff in the `www` folder in your Eclipse project. Your `www` folder should look something like this:

```
app
 |-controller
 |-model
 |-store
 |-view
index.html
app.js
sencha-touch.js
sencha-touch.css
```

Check the Sencha docs for using and creating builds for your app:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/building

Good luck!